# Python Tkinter, очистка полей StringVar объектов

Tags: python, tkinter

Как очистить текст из StringVar объектов?

Comment: `var = StringVar()` `var.set("")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект класса `StringVar()`, имеет методы `get`/`set`.
Соответственно: `get()` - извлекаем значение, `set("value")` - задаем значение

Если хотите очистить - задаете пустую строку:

```
obj = StringVar()
obj.set("")
```